# How to make Flutter animation like this?

Tags: flutter, animation

Any code example is welcome, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabBar` does this animation by default...

You can look at its source code from the IDE or [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/77d935af4d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/tabs.dart#L608) to see how it's done.

This [page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) has documentation, video, and examples if you want to use it directly in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample.
You can use TabBar widget.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text("Demo"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: "Wellbeing",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Cleaning",
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Self-care",
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Center(child: Text("Wellbeing")),
          Center(child: Text("Cleaning")),
          Center(child: Text("Self-care")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```